# Why can I still access a buffer after transferring it to a node worker?

Tags: node.js, multithreading

## [From Node's Docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_port_postmessage_value_transferlist)

`port.postMessage(value[, transferList])` (this is the same as worker.postMessage)

> transferList may be a list of ArrayBuffer, MessagePort and FileHandle objects. After transferring, they will not be usable on the sending side of the channel anymore (even if they are not contained in value). Unlike with child processes, transferring handles such as network sockets is currently not supported.

What exactly does a "transfer" entail? The code below doesn't behave how I predict:

`a.js`

```js
import { Worker } from "worker_threads";
import chalk from "chalk";
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

const thisChalk = chalk.blue;
const log = (s) => console.log(thisChalk`Thread A: ${s}`);

const data = await fs.readFile("./threads/test"); // buffer
const worker = new Worker("./threads/noBlock/b.js");
log(data.buffer.byteLength);
worker.postMessage(data, [data.buffer]); // data should be undefined after?
log(`post transfer > ${chalk.whiteBright(data.buffer.byteLength)}`);
worker.on("message", (message) => {
  log(`B > ${message}`);
  const ui8data = new Uint8Array(data);
  log(ui8data);
  worker.postMessage({ payload: "TERMINATE" });
});
worker.on("exit", (code) => {
  log(`received termination from B w/ code > ${code}`);
  log("exiting");
  const ui8data = new Uint8Array(data);
  log("Final data view >");
  log(ui8data); // Despite having modified the buffer that was *transferred* to b and never sent back it is still usable and its contents are unmodified.
});
```

`b.js`

```js
import { parentPort } from "worker_threads";
import chalk from "chalk";

const thisChalk = chalk.green;
const log = (s) => console.log(thisChalk`Thread B: ${s}`);

parentPort.on("message", (m) => {
  if (m.payload === "TERMINATE") {
    process.exit(0);
  }
  log(m);
  m[0] = 255;
  log(m); // This changes m in this context but not in a's context.
  parentPort.postMessage("ping");
});
```

`test`

```
lorem ipusm dolor sign
```

Full output of running `a.js` (with node)

```
Thread A: 8192
Thread A: post transfer > 8192
Thread B: 108,111,114,101,109,32,105,112,117,115,109,32,100,111,108,111,114,32,115,105,103,110
Thread A: B > ping
Thread A: 108,111,114,101,109,32,105,112,117,115,109,32,100,111,108,111,114,32,115,105,103,110
Thread B: 255,111,114,101,109,32,105,112,117,115,109,32,100,111,108,111,114,32,115,105,103,110
Thread A: received termination from B w/ code > 0     
Thread A: exiting
Thread A: Final data view >
Thread A: 108,111,114,101,109,32,105,112,117,115,109,32,100,111,108,111,114,32,115,105,103,110
```

The buffer in B seems like a copy since changes in B don't reflect in A, and the buffer is still accessible in A when it has never been transferred back. Why does it not truly "transfer" the data?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the documentation and/or the implementation in Node 14 LTS for the transferList parameter functioning as expected. Upgrading to Node 15 solved the issue and the code correctly throws an error.